# Expand exchange online public folders from Outlook VSTO addin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have a simple VSTO outlook addin that needs to move email messages into public folders.  It works fine except when outlook is first launched. After a first launch of outlook (office 365 business) if I try and use the addin to move a message into a public folder using GetFolderFromID(IDValueStoredInMyAddin) I get an error "The operation failed. The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook".  If after starting outlook the user manually expands the public folders tree then the addin works without this error.  Any ideas what is going on here?  Is there a way from within a VSTO addin for expand public folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook initializes stores on first access. Try to specify the store entry id (second parameter when calling `GetFolderFromID`) or open the store first using `Namespacve.GetStorefromID` followed by `Store.GetFolderFromID`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and looks like it is working with this:

```
public string GetStoreID()
{
  if (Properties.Settings.Default.SharedFolderEmail != "")
  {
    Outlook._NameSpace nSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

    Outlook.Recipient recip = nSpace.CreateRecipient(Properties.Settings.Default.SharedFolderEmail);
    if (recip.Resolve())
    {
      Outlook.Folder root = nSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox) as Outlook.Folder;
      return root.StoreID;
    }
    else
    {
      return "";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Outlook.Folder root = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
    return root.StoreID;
  }
}


Outlook._NameSpace nSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

_Archive = nSpace.GetFolderFromID(FolderToMonitor_EntryID, GetStoreID());

_Archive.Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(ItemAdded);

GC.KeepAlive(_Archive);
```